# Determination of vibration parameters of the damped tuning fork

Tags: vibrations

I have the tables with values of measurement results.

[image]

Where **A<sub>0</sub>** is the initial value of the amplitude. 
**A** is ending value of the amplitude.
**t** is time between starting and ending point.
**f** is frequency of tuning fork.

I need to count the `damping factor - β`, `relaxation time - τ` and `logarithmic decrement suppression - λ`.

This is how  I do it:

1) I am using the logarithmic decrement suppression pattern

[image]

Where **A<sub>n</sub>** is my **A<sub>0</sub>** and **A** is **A<sub>m</sub>** (I am not sure about that)

I did five measurements, so **A<sub>n</sub> = 1**, and **A<sub>m</sub>=5**

[image]

2) Now I can count `damping factor - β` using pattern below:

[image]

Where **T** is is the vibration period which is calculated from the formula:

[image]

[image]

[image]

3) A the end I can calculate the `relaxation time - τ`:

[image]

Are my calculations good? If not, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Without units, a number does not mean much.

Comment: True, but the calculations are good? The way I do it is correct?

Comment: I would first estimate the Q factor (which does not have units).

Comment: Why do I need the Q factor?